# how to await a declaration?

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await

Hi I try to set option for my Datatable then to add a new field in my objects but I need to await those dtOptions to be done how can I await the this.dtoptions in ngOnInit

```js
export class MyDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  grades: any = [];
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  buffer: any = "";

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private _auth: AuthService, private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.dtOptions = {
      order: [[0, "desc"]],
      responsive: true,
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 2,
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
        this.http
          .post<DataTablesResponse>('http://localhost:4000/grade/readByStudentId', {
            login: this._auth.getUserData().login,
            dataTablesParameters
          }).subscribe(resp => {
          this.grades = resp.data;
          callback({
            recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
            recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
            data: []
          });
        });
      },
      columns: [{data: 'id'}, {data: 'firstName'}, {data: 'lastName'}]
    };

    await this.grades.forEach(grade => {
      this.getTpName(grade.tp_id)
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe(tpName => {
          grade.push({tpName : tpName});
        });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the functionality that you want after the post functionalities to be inside the subscribe() of post function.

Move the below code inside the subscription after the line you asign the grades value

```
this.grades.forEach(grade => { this.getTpName(grade.tp_id) .pipe(take(1)) .subscribe(tpName => { grade.push({tpName : tpName}); }); });
```